# Get props from React container to functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-redux-i18n

This is how my container looks like:

```
class Shipping extends React.PureComponent {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
   }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.match.params.shippingId !== this.props.match.params.shippingId) {
        
           this.props.getShippingDetails(this.props.match.params.shippingId)
       }
   }
   render = () => this.props.isLoading ? null : <ShippingView removeOrder={this.props.removeOrder} />
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ shippingDetails}) => ({
    isLoading: shippingDetails.isLoading
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getShippingDetails: (id) => dispatch(shippingActions.getShippingDetails(id)),
    removeOrder: (id) => dispatch(shippingActions.removeOrder(id))
})

export default () => Shared.accessPageWrapper([["acess:all"], ["admin:control", "navigation/shopping:view"]], (connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Shipping)), <Shared.AccessDeniedView  />)
```

This is how my functional component looks like:

```
export const accessPageWrapper = (
    permissionsAllowed = [],
    component = null,
    accessDeniedView,
    accessDenied = true
) => {
    const permissions = useSelector(state => state.user.permissions)
    const permitted = permissionsAllowed.some((permission) => permission.every(el => permissions.includes(el)), false)
    if (permitted) {
        const Component = component
        return <Component />
    }
    return accessDenied ? accessDeniedView : null
}
```

I'm not able to pass the props through the functional component as following:

```
const Component = component
return <Component {...props} />
```

Due to that issue, I'm getting the following error because my prop's prams are undefined.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

I have no idea how to fix this :/ Would you be so kind to help me?
Also, I don't want to change the above functional component to a class component.
Is there any way I can retrieve the props to the component? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You shouldn't use `this` in functional component

Comment: Is `accessPageWrapper` supposed to be a Higher Order Component? Where iis `accessDenied` defined? Also, function components are instanceless so there is no `this` for them, or rather, `this` is simply undefined.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the parameter. Please have a look. Yes, it is a Higher Order Component @DrewReese

Comment: @UKS yes, that was an example. my question is how do I get the props here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing the return of a component. Higher Order Components consume a component (and other possible parameters) and return a new, decorated component.

```
export const accessPageWrapper = (
  permissionsAllowed = [],
  component = null,
  accessDeniedView,
  accessDenied = true
) => (props) => { // <-- return a functional component
  const permissions = useSelector((state) => state.user.permissions);
  const permitted = permissionsAllowed.some(
    (permission) => permission.every((el) => permissions.includes(el)),
    false
  );
  if (component && permitted) { // <-- Ensure component exists!
    const Component = component;
    return <Component {...props} />; // <-- spread passed props to Component
  }
  return accessDenied ? accessDeniedView : null;
};
```

Probably need to update the export.

```
import { accessPageWrapper } from '.....';

...

export default accessPageWrapper(
  [["acess:all"], ["admin:control", "navigation/shopping:view"]], 
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Shipping), 
  <Shared.AccessDeniedView />,
);
```

Comment: props are getting passed as a parameter automatically?

Comment: @Dayan Automatically? No, I don't think so. Your HOC has to pass them along to the component it is wrapping. Remember, HOC consumes a component, and returns a component. All react components *can* receive a props object.

Comment: I have added this part to my 'acessPageWrapper' function -> "=> (props) => {"
It is breaking the code. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: @Dayan Can you explain a bit more how the code breaks? Is there an error?

Comment: There are no errors. I'm getting an empty page. Also, it is not hitting the function. I have added a debugger. It seems like it can not find this function. When I remove this part "(props) => ", it is working OK

Comment: Now I'm  getting this error -> "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it." @drewreese

Comment: @Dayan Ok, maybe my updated decorated component export suggestion isn't *quite* right. Just tried this code in a [comdesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-props-from-react-container-to-functional-component-1q6dz?file=/src/App.js) and it seems to function as I'd expect. Can you try reproducing your code into a *running* codesandbox that we can debug in?